# Injecting UrlEncoded string into page - Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, markup, urlencode

It seems the following markup is rendered differently in Firefox and Chrome, and I'm not sure how to prevent it:

```
<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+") %>
<%= "<a href='#' name='" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+") + "'>stuff</a>"%>
```

In Firefox it looks like:
`%2b<a name="+" href="#">stuff</a>`
In Chrome it looks like:
`%2b<a name="%2b" href="#">stuff</a>`

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a difference in the way Firebug and the Chrome developer tools display the name. If you view the source you'll find `%2b` in both, and that's what it'll be if you're referring to it in script (or in a link such as `<a href="#%2b">`).

Comment: It's not just developer tools. If I do a postback with name as the argument, I get a decoded string in Firefox and original string in Chrome. This is the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by manually checking in code behind whether returned string contained '+' or '=' and UrlEncoded appropriately. While this is not a great solution, it was acceptable in my case since I know decoded string contained both '+' and '=', so I could infer whether it was encoded depending on whether they were present.